# Node.js throws er Unhandled error event

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have installed node, npm in my Centos 6 server, and i am using [putty](http://www.putty.org/) for running commands at server.

Node is installed correctly at root and running awesome at anywhere at server.

my project is at /home/shaadise/public_html/Ikon

I have created a **hello.js** file /home/shaadise/public_html/Ikon

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080);

console.log('Server started');
```

while running js:

```
root@vps [/home/shaadise/public_html/Ikon]# node hello.js
Server started

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/shaadise/public_html/Ikon/hello.js:6:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
root@vps [/home/shaadise/public_html/Ikon]#  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
-bash: throw: command not found
-bash: //: is a directory
```

Question: **where i have to put my node js file and how can i access it????**

i tested to run command:

```
root@vps [/home/shaadise/public_html/Ikon]# netstat -plnt | grep ':8080'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      27111/nginx
```

Comment: Another program using port 8080?

Comment: No i have tested only one program is running on port:8080. Mentioned in question now

Comment: you can keep you file anywhere you wish. Check user-permissions once.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This `Error: listen EADDRINUSE` categorically means that either you or a daemon is running another application on 8080.

However, to check, try running on a different port?

***-edit-*** as this is getting quite a few upvotes, I thought i'd add a bit of additional debug into it.

Pretty much all node.js tutorials default to port 8080 for running.  This is because it is similar to the default port 80 used by other web services, such as Apache or NGinX.

In order to determine if another application is running on the same port, you can use `netstat -a` to see all active connections and their ports, and then grep that list to find any process connected on the same port as your Node.js application.

It doesn't really matter which port your Node application runs on, as long as it's a free port.  Ultimately, when you deploy into production, you would sync up whatever content server you are using (Apache/NGinX) to use the same port.

Comment: The answer above explains how to check what's running on various ports.  Implementation is then just a case of using the standard node instantiation for the web server

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Linux based system, first you have to list all the programs that are using that particular port and kill them(meaning stop them)

exemple: I want to list all programs that are using the 3000 port

```
fuser 3000/tcp
```

then pick the process ID, which is in the right side of the obtained line of text and issue the kill command

exemple : if have a process ID with the value of 2345 then the command will be

```
kill 2345
```

Answer (score 3):

A common situation to get this error is when one does the following:

1. startup **something**
2. use **Ctrl+z** and put it into background
3. try to startup **something** again

The good way to go would be always try to hit **Ctrl+c** first which sends signal to the application (which may decide to shutdown).
You can read more about it here:
[What is the difference between Ctrl-z and Ctrl-c in the shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510811/what-is-the-difference-between-ctrl-z-and-ctrl-c-in-the-shell)

Answer (score 3):

The server is running in background; it's happing, usually, when you don't kill the process.
To solve this you can put on the terminal:

> ps | grep 'node'

This code will show you a process that have a specific number, use the next code to kill the process:

> kill -9 "specific number"

You can use sudo if this doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If closing the process which is using that port doesn't fix it , try the below solutions.

#### Installing the below package fixed it for me forever.

> **`npm install ws@3.3.2 --save-dev --save-exact`**

#### Run this command in your terminal :

> `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`

**For Arch Linux add this line to /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf:**

`fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288`

Then execute:

`sysctl --system`

https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers#the-technical-details